# How do I add String into ArrayList by use BufferedReader?

Tags: java

I want to add my words into my input_words by user System.in, I tried look at online and I did test many way, but it doesn't work. Anyone can help?

In my code, when I run it, it will ask me to put String1, 2, 3...7, but I want to put it into input_words.

Thank you...

Here is my code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<String> input_words = new ArrayList<String>();

    input_words.add("SCHOOLWORKTWO");
    input_words.add("BALCONY");
    input_words.add("INSIST"); 
    input_words.add("SALTPETER");
    input_words.add("BOLTON");
    input_words.add("KITSCHY");
    input_words.add("CLIENTELE");
    String s1 = getInput("Enter a String String 1: ");
    String s2 = getInput("Enter a String String 2: " );
    String s3 = getInput("Enter a String String 3: " );
    String s4 = getInput("Enter a String String 4: " );
    String s5 = getInput("Enter a String String 5: " );
    String s6 = getInput("Enter a String String 6: " );
    String s7 = getInput("Enter a String String 7: " );
    System.out.println(s1 + ", " + s2+", " + s3+", " + s4+", " + s5+", " + s6+", " + s7);       // Should use this string as input_words.add Array
    System.out.print(getTiles(input_words, DEFAULT_SPLITTER)); // Make sure to use DEFAULT_SPLITTER

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having trouble understanding exactly what you are looking for... but if you are saying you want to write information using System.in, you need to use a Scanner.

Something like this:

```
ArrayList<String> input_words = new ArrayList<String>();

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

input_words.add( input.next() );
```

If you always want a specific number of words inputted each time, you could use a for loop like this (example is with seven words):

```
ArrayList<String> input_words = new ArrayList<String>();

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

for (int i=0 ; i<7 ; i++) {     
    input_words.add( input.next() );
}
```

I might misunderstand your question, but I'm not sure.

Comment: This one would be help too, but my question is about convert my command line which is Enter a String 1, Enter a String 2.... Enter a String 7, then I want all those string into my input_words Arraylist. I try to figure out many way, but i did not know how to do it.

Comment: If you want the program to ask the user to enter string 1, string 2, etc. you can simply place a "System.out.println("Enter string"+i)" statement right above the input_words.add( input.next() ) (inside the loops).

Answer (score 1):

use something like [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to construct the desired string, and then add it to your list, e.g.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.append(s1);
sb.append(",");
sb.append(s2);
.
.
sb.append(",");
sb.append(s7);

input_words.add(sb.toString());
```